# url extension remove with php

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I have a dilemma here...

At the moment I'm launing a website and there are a lot of old url that needs to be redirected to it's new url without .stm extension. And the new site is running Durpal.

Ex.

http://www.foo.com/foo/bar.stm  --> http://www.foo.com/foo/bar

So I went looking more into nginx.conf setting to rewrite the url before it even hit setting.php that is being used by drupal. Turns out that my host doesn't let me touch the conf file on the root folder. but my only solution is add this to the conf file in root

```
server { location / { rewrite ^(.*)\.stm$ $1 permanent; } }
```

At this point, I'm running out of options but to redirect every pages in Drupal manually ( that is roughly about 650 pages )

I've also tried every other modules, but non offers extension strip redirect.

My other option is using 404 landing page to run php and redirect any url with .stm and redirect with scrubbed url without .stm and stays in 404 if it's not a .stm url.

This is my best bet, [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) 
But it's over complicated just for a extension strip and redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to check if the requested URI contains ".stm", and if so then redirect to the exact same URI with the ".stm" ripped. Put something like this in your settings.php:

```
if (strrpos(request_uri(), '.stm') !== FALSE) {
    header("Location: " . str_replace('.stm', '', request_uri()));
    exit;
}
```